# Why are both variable counts increasing on my 'isValidChessBoard' code from Ch5 of 'Automate The Boring Stuff with Python'?

Tags: python

I'm on Chapter 5 of Automate The Boring Stuff With Python and am trying the Chess Board challenge at the end of the chapter where your program should receive a dictionary value describing a chess board, and check that it's valid.

The first part of my code which checks that no side has more than one king works, however i'm running into problems with the second part, which should check that no side has more than 16 pieces.

When I run the code, both bPieceCount and wPieceCount seem to increase in tandem, so if the code sees a black piece, it will add 1 to bPieceCount, but also wPieceCount. The code after line 28 is just to check that it's working correctly, and will be taken out in the final version once i've completed the rest of it.

Thanks for your help.

```
def isValidChessBoard(board):

    #Check kings
    bKingCount = 0
    wKingCount = 0
    for v in board.values():
        if v == 'bking':
            bKingCount = bKingCount + 1
        if v == 'wking':
            wKingCount = wKingCount + 1

    if bKingCount != 1:
        print('False')
    elif wKingCount != 1:
        print ('False')
    else:

        #Check nobody has more than 16 pieces
        bPieceCount = 0
        wPieceCount = 0
        for v in board.values():
            if v == 'bking' or 'bqueen' or 'brook' or 'bknight' or 'bbishop' or 'bpawn':
                bPieceCount = bPieceCount + 1
            if v == 'wking' or 'wqueen' or 'wrook' or 'wknight' or 'wbishop' or 'wpawn':
                wPieceCount = wPieceCount + 1

        if bPieceCount > 16 or wPieceCount > 16:
            print('False')
            print(wPieceCount)
            print(bPieceCount)
        else:
            print ('Continue')
            print(wPieceCount)
            print(bPieceCount)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lines:

```py
if v == 'bking' or 'bqueen' or 'brook' or 'bknight' or 'bbishop' or 'bpawn':
    bPieceCount = bPieceCount + 1
if v == 'wking' or 'wqueen' or 'wrook' or 'wknight' or 'wbishop' or 'wpawn':
    wPieceCount = wPieceCount + 1
```

Don't work as you expect because implementing an `or` statement in this situation will always be `True`.

Let's take a simpler example:

```py
example_num = 1
example_bool = a == 1 or 2  # Evaluates to True!
```

The reason for this is that `example_num == 1` and `2` each evaluate as their own boolean statements. Since any non-empty value in python evaluates to True, your if statements do the same.
To solve your problem, you could use the `in` keyword:

```py
if v in ('bking', 'bqueen', 'brook', 'bknight', 'bbishop', 'bpawn'):
    bPieceCount = bPieceCount + 1
if v in ('wking', 'wqueen', 'wrook', 'wknight', 'wbishop', 'wpawn'):
    wPieceCount = wPieceCount + 1
```

Which will check if v is any of those values.